# show view only when uitableviecell is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` and an overlaying view. In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` the view is shown but I want it to hide as soon as the user lets go of the screen. So the view is only shown when the users presses a cell and hidden as soon as he lets go.
I tried using `touchesEnded` but I can't get it to work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.colorView.hidden = false
    self.colorView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: hide your view on touchesEnd method -(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: Have you tried adding gesture recognisers to the cell?

Comment: @CongTran thanks for the tip, i tried this but it seems that touchesbegan is not called when i select a tableview cell

Comment: Did you used a custom TableviewCell? If yes, you can call this method on your tableviewcell, then  send this event to your viewcontroller.

Comment: @CongTran no i didn't, but i know how to make custom cell etc. But how can i send the event to the vc?

Comment: You can create a delegate or block from your tableviewcell then handler it on viewcontroller.

Comment: And I wonder why you don't use Maulik's answer. I think it'll fine on your case?

Comment: @CongTran The cell only deselects when another cell is selected. not when touch is ended. You have an example on your previous comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `touchesEnded` method on your `TableViewCell`to detect when user end touch on this cell. Then use delegate to send this event to your `viewcontroller`
Here for example:

YourTableViewCell.swift

```
    protocol YourTableViewCellDelegate: class {
        func endTouch(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    }


    class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
        weak var delegate: YourTableViewCellDelegate?
        var indexPath: NSIndexPath

       // Add Your Other method
        func bind(index: NSIndexPath) {
             self.indexPath = index
        }

        override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            self.delegate?.endTouch(self.indexPath)
        }
    }
```

YourViewController.swift

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, YourTableViewCellDelegate {

    // Add Your Other method

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.bind(indexPath)
    }

    // MARK: - YourTableViewCellDelegate
    func endTouch(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.colorView.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: It works thank you! But can you tell me how i can retrieve the index path (row)?

Answer (score 0):

You should call colorView.hidden from your touches ended override.

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        self.colorView.hidden = true
}
```